# When mocking a React hook in Jest, it mocks all hooks in that folder

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm currently testing a React hook. In the same folder as this React hook, is another React hook I need to mock in the test. Example:

```
jest.mock("this/location/has/both/hooks", () => ({
  firstHook: jest.fn(),
}))

describe("testHook", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    firstHook.mockImplementation(() => {})
  })

  test("this is a test", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => secondHook({ param1, param2 }))

    expect(result.current.property).toBe(something)
  })
})
```

The second hook is also being mocked - unexpectedly. How can I mock one without mocking all the hooks in this location?

Answer (score 0):

To mock only specific properties in a module, see [Mocking Partials](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials)

For your case,

```
jest.mock("this/location/has/both/hooks", () => ({
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('this/location/has/both/hooks');

  return {
    __esModule: true, // for ES6 imports
    ...originalModule,
    firstHook: jest.fn(),
  };
});
```